# Does geofirestore retrieves all documents?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, geofirestore

I have `users` collection in Firestore each document of which has the format `{ d: <obj>, g: <str: geohash>, l: <GeoPoint> }`, and I use [geofirestore-js](https://github.com/geofirestore/geofirestore-js) on my client app to perform a Nearby Search, and it's been working great.
However, I wonder if [geofirestore-js](https://github.com/geofirestore/geofirestore-js) retrieves all the documents from `users` beforehand behind the scenes, and performs the calculation to narrow down the result.
The reason I'm asking is that, according to [Firebase official document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas), it is NOT the number of API calls, but number of documents which counts.
Or, does the library magically narrow down the result on the server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not read all the documents.  That wouldn't scale at all.  Geo queries use a special encoding that can be efficiently queried to find only the documents that match.

It even says on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/geofirestore/geofirestore-js):

> GeoFirestore selectively loads only the data near certain locations,
>   keeping your applications light and responsive, even with extremely
>   large datasets.

Comment: Note that GeoFirestore reads documents in a rectangular range, which means it reads more documents than it actually returns. In practice I typically see it reading between 3x and 8x more documents than it returns. This is inherent in how the algorithm/library works, but it's something to be aware of. If you'd like to learn more about all of this, check out my talk on the subject: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mx1mMdHBi5Q

Comment: Interesting. Thanks. That helps.

Comment: "GeoFirestore selectively loads only the data near certain locations, keeping your applications light and responsive, even with extremely large datasets." 

If you re-ran the same query a 2nd time from the same location, what happens?